# Trim water damaged leaves?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors, pruning

I had a plant which was in too low of light and not sufficient drainage.  After repotting with better soil and good drainage new leaves are coming out and soil is drying up nicely between watering.  What I am wondering is if I should trim/prune the old damaged leaves or leave them be?
[image: IMG0]

Comment: Cut off LEAFLETS that are obviously not healthy nor green enough to be able to make photosynthesis to make food for the plant..  You've got a few things going on here.  Please send a close up of those leaves including a shot of beneath those leaves.  You have either overfertilized or your tap water has added too much salt to your soil.  That is the reason for the burned tips.  What are those white spots?  This looks like repotting into fresh bagged potting soil, dunking your entire plant...in, well need more information before saying anymore.  We'll help with the pruning, too.  More info pls!

Comment: @stormy thanks! I'll add pics and explanation tomorrow as I really want to nurse this little guy back to health, just never had to do it with something that looks so "damaged".  However I am surprised at how alive and green the new leaves are which gives me hope!